# Cannot connect to IIS FTP server outside LAN

Tags: windows, networking, ftp, port, iis-8

Probably has been asked before.

I've set up an FTP server in IIS on an Windows 8 machine using the following steps:

1. Installed IIS FTP services
2. Set a static public IP and a static internal LAN IP, set up Router
3. Created a new FTP site in IIS manager

   - created a root ftp folder, gave test_user r/w permissions
   - Required SSL, selected self-generated certificate
   - Entered the static LAN ip of my machine, used port 21
   - Enabled Basic authentication
   - Allowed authorization for "selected user": test_user
   - Logged successfully as test_user into the ftp server from within the local network.
   - Remoted to an outside server, browsed to [publicip]:21 and ftp://[mypublicip]
   - FAIL
4. Troubleshooting

   - Tried to access the FTP server from another PC on the LAN using the [PublicIP]:[PortNumber]
   - Turned off Windows firewall
   - No SSL
   - Basic Authentication, same test_user
   - Connected my computer directly to WAN, without router (I have an ethernet line to WAN, no modem - so I could just plug in the cable)
   - tried a different port for the FTP server (1342)
   - checked my public IP
   - remoted to the same server, tried browsing for my FTP again
   - went through several combinations of the above steps. at one point, the combination contained all of the troubleshooting steps.
   - FAIL

So no matter what I did, I could not access the FTP server remotely. Really mystified.

What could I have done wrong? Can the ISP block FTP even if you use non-standard ports?

Comment: Your ISP may be blocking incoming FTP, as they should. Is there some other way to do what you're trying to do. Running an FTP server on Windows 8 isn't exactly an ideal setup.

Comment: That's what I though too. Would changing the port number help? I tried a few other port numbers, but that did not work

Comment: Your best chance would be to try an unregistered (high) port number (between 1024 and 65535). The easiest way to check if the port is open is with the ShieldsUp test https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?bh0bkyd2

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to allow FTP though? It's a problematic protocol, as it doesn't play nicely with firewalls, and by default the credentials are transmitted in the clear. There are usually better/safer alternatives.

Comment: You can use SSL. What do you mean by "in the clear"? There may be better alternatives, they don't answer the question of why it's not working. curiousity, i guess.

Comment: In the clear means the credentials aren't encrypted by default. It's a very outdated, insecure protocol. Yes you can use SSL, and this will certainly help. As mentioned, it's probably your ISP blocking registered ports, so a high port number may work.

Comment: I'm having same issue with the FTPS but for FTP I've allowed incoming/outgoing rules in the Firewall and it started working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can access the FTP server when connected directly to the modem. I accidentally forgot to change site bindings (wrong ip) in IIS before changing the network connection. Of course I still can't connect through the router, with the firewall disabled. The issue is the router (or maybe Im an idiot) and I can't find any solution aside from trying another router.

Answer (score -1):

Is your router translating the public IP down to the internal lan IP? This is typically done through a NAT rule in the router to tell it where to send the public traffic to inside your network.

Comment: Yes it is. I added the relevant NAT rule {InternalIP; Port 21 etc; TCP}. That did not work, so I just connected to WAN directly, no routing. That was a fail too.

Comment: Is there a place in router to allow specific traffic from public to lan? Similar to firewall rules but on router between public and internal network.

Comment: yes it has allowed ports (just the ports, no addresses) and allowed port forwarding (both ports and IP addresses). I did port forwarding first, but when then failed I also changed the allowed ports. But none of that worked. I honestly think its the IP blocking FTP. But can they block it if you use a non-standard port?

Comment: Ah - could be isp - would check with them - not sure if they could block on non standard port.